# Java Swing / AWT with setIcon Gif Animated High Load

Tags: java, swing, animation, awt

I Have **1 single java app**. ONly Containing **1 JMenu** with **48 JMenuItem(s)**.
Each JMenuItems i set the **Icon with Animated GIF**.

I have no problem creating it. 
And I also have no problem when Running it. 
But the problem came, when I running it, and then viewing the JMenuItem.
My **GIF(s) Animation** seems consuming the PC Process very high! 
And the ANimation seems jumping too fast! It's not the usual animation framerate, tough.

So anytime when I run the java app, and then **trying** the **JMenuItem**, **The CPU Process
is getting higher...!**

Look at [this Preview:](http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/3766/jvahighloadjmenuitemcon.jpg) It's taken when My java app runs. 
What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solutions guys! The GIF Animation has lots of frames. In each frames they have their own timing. When I reopened one single GIF Animation File, I could see clearly that the 0-time framerate is the problem. Now I should Changed it to somewhat above 0.1 framerate, that's all problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

What result do you get from this SSCCE?  My system peaks to 40 at start-up then jumps to an average of around 20-30.  The rendering of the animated GIFs is somewhat jerky.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Gif48 {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String url = "http://1point1c.org/gif/thum/plnttm.gif";
                int w = 12;
                int h = 4;
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(h,w,2,2));
                String pre = "<html><body><img src='";
                String post = "'>";
                for (int ii=0; ii<w*h; ii++) {
                    JLabel l = new JLabel(
                        pre + url + post );
                    l.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    l.setOpaque(true);
                    p.add(l);
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> What's the best way to solve this?

Don't use animated GIFs in the controls of GUIs.

Comment: hahaha.... lol.
I have found the solutions guys!
The GIF Animation has lots of frames. In each frames they have their own timing. When I reopened one single GIF Animation File, I could see clearly that the 0-time framerate is the problem. Now I should Changed it to somewhat above 0.1 framerate, that's all problem solved. Hehehehe... I still use Those GIF Animated FIles on my GUI and my CPU PRocess is not high anymore. :D @Andrew Thompson